# Outlook VBA for marking a new mail as a task before sending

Tags: vba, outlook

I have tried this:

```
Sub SendAwaitingResponse()
  Dim mail As MailItem
  Set mail = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
  mail.MarkAsTask (olMarkToday)
  mail.Categories = "Awaiting Response"
  mail.Send
End Sub
```

with the following error:

> Draft Items cannot be marked. MarkAsTask is only valid on items that have been sent or received.

It is possible to click "Follow up" in the UI, and then the mail will be marked as task after sent. I see no way to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a macro associated to a button "Send Awaiting Response", in order to mark sent emails with a custom property:

```
Sub SendAwaitingResponse()
    Dim Mail As MailItem
    Set Mail = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Dim Property As UserProperty
    Set Property = Mail.UserProperties.Add("FlagAwaitingResponse", olYesNo)
    Property.Value = True
    Mail.Send
End Sub
```

Inside the ThisOutlookSession object, subscribe to items added to the Sent Items folder. Items marked with the custom property will be marked as an Outlook task.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim SentItems As Folder
    Set SentItems = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set Items = SentItems.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim Mail As MailItem
    Set Mail = Item

    Set Property = Mail.UserProperties("FlagAwaitingResponse")
    If Property Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Mail.Categories = "Awaiting Response"
    Mail.MarkAsTask (olMarkToday)
    Mail.Save
End Sub
```

Don't forget to enable Outlook macros for this to work.

Comment: This just helped me out! Thank you. I know really old, but taking a stab at asking: how can I have this script ignore any meeting requests I send out? Every time I send a meeting request, even though I don't trigger the macro, I get a Run-time error '13: Type mismatch and then when I click debug, the "Set Mail = Item" is yellow highlighted.

Comment: I guess you'd need to check for the type of the Item before actually using it as a MailItem.

Comment: That's what I did! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to listed to the Items.ItemAdd even on the Sent Items folder and call MarkAsTask on the message passed to the event handler.