# How to popup question, whether to flag, after pressing send button?

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there a way to ask (popup) if I want to flag the email after I press the send button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Application.ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend) event to display a `MsgBox` asking whether to flag or not.

Then as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415104/outlook-vba-for-marking-a-new-mail-as-a-task-before-sending), you'll need to listen to the `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder and call `MarkAsTask` on the message passed to the event handler.

So add the following code to `ThisOutlookSession` - use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to bring up the VB editor.

[image]

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim SentItems As Folder
    Set SentItems = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set Items = SentItems.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Dim property As UserProperty
        Set property = Item.UserProperties("FlagForFollowUp")

        If property Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        Item.MarkAsTask olMarkThisWeek
        Item.Save
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Dim prompt As String
        prompt = "Would you like to flag this item?"

        If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Flag item") = vbYes Then
            Dim property As UserProperty
            Set property = Item.UserProperties.Add("FlagForFollowUp", olYesNo)
            property.Value = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i dont know how to install this code into outlook. can you pls help ?

Comment: and if the answer is yes, which code shall i write to flag the email i am sending ? (you wrote only "do whatever you wanted to do"

Comment: Do you have a specific time period in mind? Are you flagging the email to be followed up today/tomorrow/next week/no date/or custom time period? Also see [`MailItem.MarkAsTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.markastask).

Comment: good question, "this week" is just fine for me. and if you can share a link which shows how to implement this code into outlook, it would be perfect.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I added the code and it asks the question but when i select "yes" , it does not flag it. the last part of the code needs some tweaking...

Comment: after restarting, it didnt pop up at all... before restarting at least, it was poping up...

Comment: @UmutK this is a Microsoft trick played on first time users, to allow then disallow. Google how to update Macro Setting in the Trust Center.

Comment: @niton thank you ! it worked ! but i have one more comment, it does not work when i use  Alt+Enter to send (which i use often).

Comment: @UmutK  It is either Alt+S or Ctrl+Enter

Comment: @BigBen hi again... i used this code before on Office 2016 with Pop account but it does not work on exchange account, does it matter if it's a pop account or exchange ?

Comment: I am honestly not sure.